# How to sort filenames with spaces in them and concatenate the files?

Tags: bash, zsh, filenames, cat, whitespace

I have the misfortune of dealing with filenames that contain spaces. I want to concatenate files of which filenames contain spaces. I also want to sort the filenames numerically. Obviously the following fails:

```
cat $(ls *.sql | sort -n)
```

since `foo bar.sql` is passed as two arguments to `cat`. What is the usual approach here?

Comment: The usual approach is to avoid parsing the output of `ls`. Use `find` instead. `find` can use a NUL byte as the delimiter, and both `sort` and `xargs` can accept that delimiter, so that approach can even handle filenames that contain `\n`.

Comment: Note that that code would also fail (not do what you want) if filenames contained wildcard characters (`*`, `?`, `[`), tab or newline, started with `-` or some of the `*.sql` files were of type directory (in which case `ls` lists their content).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need for `ls` here. It's the shell that lists the directory content by expanding the `*.sql` glob.

On a GNU or FreeBSD system:

```
printf '%s\0' *.sql | sort -nz | xargs -r0 cat --
```

(using `\0` instead of `\n` together with `-z/-0` makes sure it also works with file names containing newline characters).

Note that the numeric sorting with `-n` assumes the number is at the start of the filename.

Or if you have `zsh`:

```
cat ./*.sql(.n)
```

(The `n` glob qualifier is to enable numeric sorting (also works when the number is not at the start provided all file names have the same prefix (like `file12.sql`, `file2.sql`). I added `.` as well to only include regular files. Add `D` if you also want hidden files like `.foo.sql`).

Answer (score 2):

You can do `cat $(ls -1)` if you override IFS.  IFS is the shell variable that tells BASH which characters to use as a deliminator.  The default value for IFS is space, tab, newline.  If you change IFS to just newline then you can do `cat $(ls -1)`.

There is nothing wrong with the other answers but this might be a more direct answer to how to deal with spaces in general and this answer introduces the IFS variable which most are not familiar with.

```
#!/bin/bash
dir=$(mktemp -d)
for x in $(seq 10); do
    echo $x > "$dir/$(date) $x.txt"
done

pushd $dir
ls -1 $dir

# Set IFS to newline only inorder to deal with the spaces in the file names
#
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'


cat $(ls -1 $dir)


IFS=$oldIFS
```

Output

```
[sri@localhost test]$ ./test
/tmp/tmp.IuXCBzbTLj ~/test
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 10.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 1.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 2.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 3.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 4.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 5.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 6.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 7.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 8.txt
Mon Nov 17 06:38:52 EST 2014 9.txt
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Here is a link to some documentation on IFS.  http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS.  I think that I learned about it a long time ago by reading O'Rielly's BASH book.

Comment: Except with `zsh`, you also need to disable globbing with `set -f`. Leaving a variable or command substitution unquoted is the split+glob operator. You don't want the glob part here. You do want globbing for expanding `*.sql` though. So that should be: `IFS=$'\n'; set -f; cat -- $(set +f; ls -d -- *.sql)`. But, as I said, you don't need `ls` here, and you'd still have a problem with newline characters in file names.

Comment: I can't speak to zsh.  I just wanted to introduce readers to the IFS variable.  Certainly there are many better methods to solve this problem but I wanted to show the readers that it could be accomplished with a call to `ls` if that's what they feel comfortable with.

Comment: There's a [much simpler method](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168402) for people who want to stick to familiar tools. Yes, sure, `IFS` exists, but it isn't a particularly useful way to solve this particular problem. And if you do use it, use it as Stéphane suggested, in a way that at least solves the problem for all non-newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xargs` (assuming the GNU implementation) with a custom delimiter (assuming filenames don't contain newlines):

```
ls -1d -- *.sql | sort -n | xargs -d "\n" cat --
```

Comment: Note that `-d` is a GNU extension.